# If you `pip install -e .` a local package, does it count as l local application or third party library?

Tags: python

Regarding sorting imports, [PEP8 says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/):

```
Imports should be grouped in the following order:

Standard library imports.
Related third party imports.
Local application/library specific imports.
```

If I've built a package `package_a` and installed it with `pip install -e .`, then I want to import it in `package_b`, do I treat it like a third party import or a local application? Here's an example from code inside `package_b`. This treats it like a third party import:

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np
from package_a import func_a

from package_b import func_b
```

This treats it like a local application:

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np

from package_a import func_a
from package_b import func_b
```

Comment: I think the guideline is not about how you install the package, but a "semantic" difference. If you install it using pip from a shared repository or just put it in a folder in the working directory, your code will not change. I would put it in `Related third party imports`, assuming `package_b` is not part of `package_a`'s code but something you got from outside (e.g. your organization's version control repo or PyPI)

Comment: PEP 8 isn't talking about local applications, and the punctuation doesn't help clarify. It would be better written as "local application-specific and library-specific imports", that is, two different kinds of local imports: application-specific ones and library-specific ones. Basically, if it comes with Python, it's standard. If you installed it from PyPi or elsewhere and you or your colleagues did not write it, it's a third-party import. Otherwise, it's code you wrote specifically for the application or library that you are writing.

Comment: Whether you install it with `pip install -e .` or build a package for your own local PyPi repository isn't really relevant. If you did write the code, but it is shared between multiple projects, I would treat it as a 3rd-party import, even though *you* are the "3rd party".